# Jquery Mobile web app not working unless page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I currently have a web application using jquery mobile that uses phploginscript. I have my index.html which re-irects to the login.php page (this is below)

```
<?php
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<')) {
    exit('Sorry, this script does not run on a PHP version smaller than 5.3.7 !');
} else if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<')) {
    require_once('libraries/password_compatibility_library.php');
}
require_once('config/config.php');
require_once('translations/en.php');
require_once('libraries/PHPMailer.php');
require_once('classes/Login.php');
$login = new Login();
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
    include("views/logged_in.php");
} else {
    include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}
```

so when the user logs in it includes "logged_in.php" but the problem is that none of the javascript is running untill i refresh the page, as soon as i refresh the page everything is fine.

My first line of js in the page is :

```
$('#page').on('pageinit', function(){
```

thanks for your help i cant figure this one out..

Comment: the first line is $(document).on("pageshow", function() { not what i put

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick but dirty fix for this by putting the script tag into the body in the page after the main like so :

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <script>
            // Your javascript will go here
        </script>
        // And rest of your HTML content
    <div>
</body>
```

As this is a prototype design it will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

Use rel="external" when switching between pages because it will trigger a full page refresh.